# Is the compiler allowed to optimize out dynamic_cast of a volatile pointer when the compiler doesn't see a possible type which can fulfill the cast?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, volatile, dynamic-cast

Look at this little snippet:

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A() { }
};

struct B { };

bool fn() {
    A *volatile a = new A;
    return dynamic_cast<B *>(a); 
}
```

Is the compiler allowed to remove the `dynamic_cast` altogether, and transform `dynamic_cast` to a simple `nullptr;`?

The reason of this question is this [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/204430/154246).

Notes:

- Assume that volatile means that the compiler cannot assume anything about `a`, because it's volatile. Here's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51472394/is-it-allowed-for-a-compiler-to-optimize-away-a-local-volatile-variable) why.
- The fact that `dynamic_cast` may not be allowed to be removed is that there could be a type somewhere in the program, which derives from both `A` and `B`.

Comment: Are you aware of the [as-if rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule)?

Comment: Note that making `a` volatile here doesn't matter, because the compiler can see  that nobody else has the ability to touch `a`. You might try declaring `a` at namespace scope instead.

Comment: @Brian: there was some discussion about this here in SO, with no real conclusion. If you think this way, then please threat `a` as if it were in namespace scope (compilers usually respect volatile, and doesn't try optimize around its value, even if it is a local variable). `a` could come from a function, which the compiler doesn't know anything about.

Comment: @NathanOliver: yes, but understanding the as-if rule doesn't help answering this question. Suppose that I'm a compiler writer. Am I allowed to create a compiler which omits the dynamic_cast or not here?

Comment: I'm actually a little surprised that this compiles without at least warnings (which it does) - the compiler can easily see that B is not derived from A.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: there could be a type somewhere, which derives from `A` and `B` as well.

Comment: @geza wow, I haven't seen this one coming. You should put it in the question. It's important to the analysis and it's not obvious.

Comment: Another reason why volatile automatic variables don't make much sense

Comment: @Brian "_the compiler can see that nobody else has the ability to touch_" It cannot, by definition of `volatile`

Comment: @curiousguy That's not the definition of `volatile`. The definition of `volatile` from [intro.abstract] is that accesses to `volatile` variables are observable behaviour. The compiler certainly can determine that a volatile automatic variable's address doesn't leave the scope, and therefore that nobody else can touch it.

Comment: @Brian: there are opinions that observable behavior has a wider definition. Like observing with a debugger. Or, there is a possibility, that a program using debugging information, inspects itself, and even modifies a local variable from a signal handler. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51472394/is-it-allowed-for-a-compiler-to-optimize-away-a-local-volatile-variable

Comment: @Brian "_volatile automatic variable's address doesn't leave the scope, and therefore that nobody else can touch it_" That would also apply to a static volatile variable if you analyse the whole TU, or a global volatile variable if you analyse the whole program. Hopefully, the compiler is not allowed to reason about volatile variables.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a compiler can omit the call to `dynamic_cast` as per as-if rule <sup>1)</sup> if and only if it can prove that the only valid result of the call is `false`. That's simple.

The tricky part is to prove that the only valid result of `dynamic_cast` is `false`. You can prove that iff there is no class in your whole program that inherits both from `A` and `B`.

Now I am not very versed in this part, but I think you can do that when you create the binary and have all the types in your program only if it's  an executable (not a library) and only if the program doesn't dynamically link to other libraries.

---

*<sup>1)</sup> the `dynamic_cast` on pointers doesn't have side effect, it doesn't throw*

Comment: The optimization here would be not because there's no class relating them, but because the actual most derived type is known from the new-expression. Except for the quirk about whether the `volatile` means that the pointer `a` could change to point to something else between its initialization and the `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @aschepler I don't understand your comment. Yes I consider `volatile` in my analysis. It's in the question.

Comment: "only if the program doesn't dynamically link to other libraries." - that isn't covered by the standard anyway

Comment: @M.M no, but it's a reality

Comment: @bolov in reality I doubt there is any possible way that reading the value of `a` could give an unexpected result , it seems to me we are on theoretical ground here

Comment: @M.M. It shouldn't be too hard to come up with an example where a `volatile` pointer *can* change out of line, e.g. involving [DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access). But I agree that the question is impossible to answer. A better question would be: "Under which circumstances is this optimization allowed?"

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  `dynamic_cast` has no observable behavior beyond its return value.

The compiler is aware of the static type pointed to by `a`.

So under the as-if rule, the compiler is free to evaluate the dynamic cast at compile time.

In fact:

```
struct A { virtual ~A() {} };
struct B:A {};

bool foo() {
  A* a = new A;
  return dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
}
```

the above dynamic cast statement can also be optimized to `return false;`  The `new` cannot be omitted without whole program optimization as someone could overload the global operator new; once it is proven that no global operator new is overloaded, it could even optimize out the call to `new A`, as neither allocating memory by the default `operator new`, nor creating an `A` nor destroying one has any observable side effects.

Comment: 1) you mean `return true;` and 2) I was under the impression that the compiler can always elide heap allocations even if they have side effects (the operators themselves that is). http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#10

Comment: "The compiler is aware of the static type pointed to by a". But it is volatile, shouldn't the compiler ignore anything it knows about the value of `a`?

Comment: @geza What volatile means is so ambuguous that it is next to meaningless. Usually implementations do something with it.