# May a C compiler assume that a non-static local volatile variable is uninitialized?

Tags: c, volatile

In some project, I must access the machine code instructions of a function for debugging reasons.

My first approach (I decided to do it differently) was to convert a function pointer to the function to a data pointer using a `union` like this:

```
void exampleCode(void)
{
    volatile union {
        uint8_t ** pptr;
        void (* pFunc)(void);
    } u;
    uint8_t ** copyPptr;
    uint8_t * resultPtr;

#if 1
    u.pptr = (uint8_t **)0x10000000;
#endif
    u.pFunc = &myFunction;
    copyPptr = u.pptr;

    /* The problem is here: */
    resultPtr = copyPptr[109];
    *resultPtr = 0xA5;
}
```

If I remove the line `u.pptr = (uint32_t **)0x10000000`, the compiler assumes that `copyPptr` two lines below has an undefined value (according to the C standard, converting function pointers to data pointers is not allowed).

For this reason, it "optimizes" the last two lines out (which is of course not wanted)!

However, the `volatile` keyword means that the C compiler must not optimize away the read operation of `u.pptr` in the line `copyPptr = u.pptr`.

From my understanding, this also means that the C compiler must assume that it is at least possible that a "valid" result is read in this read operation, so `copyPptr` contains some "valid" pointer.

(At least this is how I understand the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51472394/is-it-allowed-for-a-compiler-to-optimize-away-a-local-volatile-variable).)

Therefore, the compiler should not optimize away the last two lines.

Is this a compiler bug (GCC for ARM) or is this behavior allowed according to the C standard?

**EDIT**

As I have already written, I already have another solution for my problem.

I asked this question because I'm trying to understand why the `union` solution did not work to avoid similar problems in the future.

In the comments, you asked me for my exact use case:

For debugging reasons, I need to access some `static` variable in some library that comes as object code.

The disassembly looks like this:

```
.text
.global myFunction
myFunction:
    ...
.L1:
    .word .theVariableOfInterest

.data:
# unfortunately not .global!
.theVariableOfInterest:
    .word 0
```

What I'm doing is this:

I set `copyPtr` to `myFunction`. If `K` is `(.L1-myFunction)/4`, then `copyPtr+K` points to `.L1` and `copyPtr[K]` points to `.theVariableOfInterest`.

So I can access the variable using `*(copyPtr[K])`.

From the disassembly of the object file, I can see that `K` is 109.

All this works fine if `copyPtr` contains the correct pointer.

**EDIT 2**

It's much simpler to reproduce the problem with `gcc -O3`:

```
char a, c;
char * b = &a;

void testCode(void)
{
    char * volatile x;
    c = 'A';
    *x = 'X';
}
```

It's true that uninitialized variables cause undefined behavior.

However, if I understand the description of `volatile` in the draft "ISO/IEC 9899:TC3" of the C99 standard correctly, a `volatile` variable would not be "uninitialized" if I stop the program in the debugger (using a breakpoint) at the line `c = 'A'` and copy the value of `b` to `x` in the debugger.

On the other hand, some other statement was saying that using `volatile` for local variables in current C++ (not C) versions already causes undefined behavior ...

Now I'm wondering what is true for modern C (not C++) versions.

Comment: There are some differing opinions in the question you link to, both in comments and in answers. With that said the compiler shouldn't optimize those two assignments away anyway (even without the `volatile` qualifier), since type-punning through unions is allowed.

Comment: Also, perhaps you have simplified your real code a bit too much, because with the code, as currently shown, there's no need for the `copyPtr` or the `resultPtr` variables. You could just use `u.pptr[109][0] = 0xa5;`

Comment: Apparently compiler optimized away something https://godbolt.org/z/xE8qMrW8x

Comment: It happens since this code is using undefined behavior. `ISO C forbids conversion of function pointer to object pointer type` so you are fighting with an optimizer.

Comment: _Side note:_ As posted, because you're using a `union` [vs. a `struct`], `copyPptr` will point to `myFunction` and _not_ `0x10000000` [or whatever else you want to set `u.pptr` to]. That's because you're setting `pFunc` _after_ you set `pptr` so you'll get the later value because of the `union`

Comment: I think this is all a red herring. Surely the problem here is the use of `uint8_t** pptr`, which is a pointer to an array of byte pointers, rather than `uint8_t* pptr`, which would be a pointer to an array of bytes. Whatever a function pointer points to (which might or might not be the assembled code), it is almost certainly not an array of byte pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added the `copyPtr` to make the question more understandable. I compiled exactly the code shown in the question with my current compiler settings to ensure that the problem is still occuring with this "simplified" code - and it still occurs. If I leave out the `volatile`, the compiler optimizes the complete function away, so it only consists of the return instruction (`bx lr`).

Comment: @CraigEstey Exactly this is what I want: I want `copyPptr` to point to the entry point of the function `myFunction`. The value `0x10000000` could be any other value (but `NULL`). It is only there because the compiler does some stupid optimizations if I leave this line out.

Comment: On my system, for `-O2`, neither `clang` 7.0.1 nor `gcc` 8.3.1 optimizes the code away. And they both generate: `movq $268435456, -8(%rsp)    # imm = 0x10000000 movq $myFunction, -8(%rsp) movq -8(%rsp), %rax movq 872(%rax), %rax movb $-91, (%rax) retq`

Comment: @rici The code I've posted is very simplified. (In reality, I would have to do some more calculations that I have removed to simplify my question.) In the end, I want to access two 32-bit words in the `.text` segment that both contain addresses (pointers) of variables.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: Perhaps you need to post a more realistic example, then. Regardless, trying to use whatever a function pointer points to as an array of pointers seems to me to be piling undefined behaviour on top of undefined behaviour. You can probably get away with treating it as an array of bytes, then constructing a pointer to the particular data values you are interested in, and then treating those specific bytes as pointers. (Although there's probably a better solution.)

Comment: If you're [just] trying to read/probe `.text`, although you can use one, I don't think you _need_ a `union` to do this. Just a cast. And, I don't think you need need double pointers

Comment: @CraigEstey Unfortunately, by casting the function pointer to a data pointer I have the same problem: The C compiler assumes that the result of casting is undefined (it is according to C language specs!) and optimizes the instructions away, too.

Comment: @MarekR The fact that conversion from function pointers to data pointers is not supported, may have the effect that the pointer `u.pptr` will contain some non-sense value (e.g. when running on a DSP with separate code and data address space). However, although the value is non-sense, it should be well-defined in this case. And in my case, `u.pptr` definitely contains the pointer that I'm interested in. So the conversion worked in the way I wanted it.

Comment: It is not problem of "support" C standard defines this as "Undefined Behavior" and compiler optimizer assumes: "code must not contain any UBs, so if I've found one then there is no path which will lead to such behavior, so I will remove such code". You need something which will convince compiler there is no UB - for example by using some compiler extension.

Comment: @MarekR I just had a look at the C99 draft "ISO/IEC 9899:TC3": If I understand the description of `volatile` in chapter 6.7.3 correctly, the C standard defines that you are allowed to put a breakpoint to the line `copyPtr = u.pptr`, set `u.pptr` to `&foo` with the debugger, continue the program and the program must then behave the same way as if there was a line `u.pptr = &foo` immediately before the breakpoint. This is definitely not the case here.

Comment: @CraigEstey That's correct: 0x10000000 is just a dummy value. The only reason for the line is: If I don't initialize `u.pptr` with any non-`NULL` value, the compiler optimizes the code away...

Comment: Create a function: `void *liar(void *addr) { return addr; }` Put it in a _separate_ `.c` file [so the compiler can't "inspect" it]. This function is like a cast that the compiler won't detect. You're already doing UB [sort of] by trying the fetch memory from the code segment, so don't worry. Then, do: `void *code = liar(myFunction); code += offsetof(.L1);  void **ptr1 = addr; int *ptr2 = *ptr1;  int myvalue = *ptr2;`

Answer (score 3):

I'd personally try compiling with the no optimization flag `-O0` (capital o, zero) to avoid the compiler "optimizing" out your code and seeing if it works then. If that's still acting problematic, consider adding the assembly `-S` flag so you can see what it's actually doing translating those instructions as and retranslating them yourself using the inline assembly `__asm__` function.

Comment: I'd say that was a good suggestion.  You can experiment here: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as I already wrote, I already have a working solution (indeed, it is based on inline assembly). The goal of my question was not finding a solution that works but the goal was understanding why the first approach did not work.